# How to Delete multiple ListID from database using this query

Tags: php, mysql

I wish to remove any duplicate listings from my database, I have trawled the internet and found a simple query, however I am unsure how to implement it into my own code

```
DELETE e.*
FROM employee e
WHERE id IN (SELECT id
             FROM 
                 (SELECT MIN(id) as id
                  FROM employee e2
                  GROUP BY first_name, last_name
                  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) x);
```

I wish to run the above query stripping all rows with the same listID found
How would I code the above query to do this?

I do not understand what the e.* and the employee e represents

My table is called listings.

I wish for the query to use the above but to DELETE all where listID=?

Could I use

```
DELETE *
FROM listings
WHERE listID IN (SELECT listID
                 FROM 
                     (SELECT MIN(listID) AS listID
                      FROM listings
                      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) x);
```

Comment: `employee e` means it is creating an alias of that table name, more verbose: `employee AS e`

Comment: ok i think im a little out of my depth here then....

Comment: DELETE *
FROM listings
WHERE listID = $listid is all i require

Comment: What is your table's structure and which rows do you want to delete? How do you define duplicates?

Comment: DELETE * FROM listings WHERE id = ? AND sellername = ? AND listID = ?

Comment: Check the syntax of the delete as there is no * or e. * needed

Answer (score 0):

The last thing you ever want to do is to run a delete without knowing exactly what it’s going to delete!

So the first step is to craft the part that determines which ones will be chosen to delete:

```
SELECT MIN(id) AS lowestid 
FROM listings
GROUP BY listid
HAVING COUNT(Listid) > 1
```

Given the following data,

```
ID   ListID
 1    100
 2    110
 3    100
 4    120
 5    110
```

It will group them by list id, so the first grouping is on 100. This grouping has two ids, 1 & 3.  So it fulfills the “having” clause because the count of ids is > 1. It selects the minimum id, 1, as the first row.

Next it groups on 110. It finds two records. This passes the “having” requirement and it selects 2 as the next row.

Next it groups on 120. It finds only one record. This fails the “having” test and is not included in the results.

So the result of this query is [1,2]

(sort order is not guaranteed unless you include sort by; but that isn’t needed here)

You can, and should, run/modify this query until you are absolutely sure you are getting the results you want.

Only then should the word delete come into play!

All you have to do now is enclose this query with parentheses, and incorporate it into the where of a delete query.

Here’s a hint “delete from” should be the last thing you type. Imagine hitting the enter key at the wrong time:

```
Delete from listings <enter>
```

And as you type where... you realize you just deleted the entire thing!

I always type select * and then when I see the results are correct, go back and replace with “delete”

```
Delete
From listings 
Where id in(    
    SELECT MIN(id) AS lowestid 
    FROM listings
    GROUP BY listid
    HAVING COUNT(Listid) > 1
)
```